# How to fix Internet Explorer PNG Bug?

Tags: internet-explorer, png, iepngfix

On this page http://browserupdate.microdual.com/ i have a bug on Internet Explorer.
How to fix it?

I had already used the DD_belatedPNG.fix() function, but it didn't worked.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDS) Timestamp: Wed, 5
>   May 2010 15:10:20 UTC
>
> Message: Syntax error Line: 1 Char: 1
>   Code: 0 URI:
>   http://ajax.microdual.com/js/belated_png.js
>
> Message: 'DD_belatedPNG' is undefined
>   Line: 202 Char: 4 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://browserupdate.microdual.com/

It looks like there is an error in your belated_png.js file.  I would start to look there.

Comment: You said that it was an error on my js file, and not a breaked link. But ok, i will mark it. Thanks for your help ;)